# Фильтр средствами JS

Tags: javascript, url

Задавал уже подобный вопрос,но пока решения подходящего не получил.Нужно сделать фильтр используя `query string`.

```
function queryStringBuilder(id) {
    var paramsId = id;

    this.getQueryString = function() {
        var queryString = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < paramsId.length; i++){
            var elem = $(paramsId[i]);

            if(elem.val().trim()){
                queryString.push((elem.attr('id') || elem.attr('name')) + "=" + escape(elem.val()));
            }
        }
        return queryString.join("&");
    }
}

var queryBuilder = new queryStringBuilder(['#dep-filter', '#month-filter']);

function showQueryString(value) {
    location.search = value;
}

$('#dep-filter').change(function(){
    showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
});

$('#month-filter').change(function(){
    showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
});
```

На данный момент есть 2 фильтра.

1) http://timelate/stuff?dep-id=158

2) http://timelate/stuff?month=2016-09

Хочу добиться того чтобы фильтры не замещали друг друга.То есть если активен фильтр `dep-id` и я выбираю второй фильтр `month`,чтобы он конкатенировался в URL к первому.А на данный момент они замещают друг друга,то есть в URL всегда активен только один фильтр.

http://timelate/stuff?dep-id=158&month=2016-09

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните, в чем вопрос? Приведите пример ожидаемого поведения. Например, есть query string `?val1=1&val2=2`. Как она должна поменяться, если мы добавляем параметры `val1` и `val3`?

Comment: Вместо ответа в комментариях, обновите Ваш вопрос с ожидаемым поведением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Написал небольшую библиотеку для этого дела.

[Вот тут](https://github.com/Thisman/UrlQueryBuilder), подключите файл URLQueryBuilder.js

А потом можете использовать:

```
var s = new URLQueryBuilder(location.href);

// если location.href = example.com
s.add('query', 'value');
s.add('anotherQuery', 'value2');
s.getUrl(); // => example.com?query=value&anotherQuery=value2&

s.delete('query'); // удаляем из строки запрос
s.getUrl(); // => example.com?anotherQuery=value2&
```

**UPD**

```
var s = new URLQueryBuilder(location.href);
$('#dep-filter').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    if(id === '') {
      location.href = s.delete("dep-id").getUrl();
    } else {
      location.href = s.add("dep-id", id).getUrl(); 
    }
});

$('#month-filter').change(function(){
    var date = $(this).val();
    if(date === '') {
      location.href = s.delete("month").getUrl();
    } else {
      location.href = s.add("month", date).getUrl();
    }
});
```

[Тут](https://output.jsbin.com/mowurovida?) можно посмотреть

Comment: http://timelate/stuff?dep-id=159&=undefined&month=2016-12&

Comment: Пока не особо что то получается

Comment: @quaresma89, а что именно не получается? Покажите код, потому что у вас тут одна из переменных равна undefined,а ключ вы вообще не передаете, можно увидеть код?

Comment: Я использовал код который вы выше написали!

Comment: @quaresma89, обновил ответ, проверьте по ссылке

Comment: @quaresma89, так же внес изменения в саму библиотеку, так что лучше обновить ее, если пользуетесь

Comment: Спасибо попробую позже1

Answer (score 3):

Я вижу следующее решение Вашей проблемы. При каждом изменении параметра, заново генерировать `query string`.

- **Плюсы:**
- Минимальная возможность допустить ошибку.
- Легко понятен.
- **Минусы:**
- Сложно поддерживать, когда параметром много.

Пример кода.

```
var queryParams ={}; 
function getQueryString(){
   var queryString = [];
   for(var k in queryParams)
     queryString.push(k+"="+escape(queryParams[k])); // escape необходима
  return queryString.join("&");
}
$('#dep-filter').change(function(){
    queryParams['depId'] = $(this).val();  
    location.search= getQueryString();
});

$('#month-filter').change(function(){
    queryParams['month'] = $(this).val();  
    location.search= getQueryString();  
});

$('.list').on('click', '.day', function(){
    queryParams['userId '] = $(this).closest('.tr').attr('data-user-id');
    location.search= getQueryString(); 
});
```

**P.S.** Конечно, можете строчку `location.search= getQueryString()` перенести в функцию `getQueryString`, тогда уберете дублирование кода. Строка `location.search= getQueryString()` оставлена в каждом методе, поскольку, возможно, Вам нужно будет получить `query string` без перезагрузки страницы. Если нет - смело выносите ее в функцию `getQueryString`.

### UPDATED

После пояснений в комментариях а также обновления вопроса, могу предложить следующее решение:

Живой пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/f4nh3jxs/).

```js
function queryStringBuilder(ids) {
  var paramsID = ids;

  this.getQueryString = function() {
    var queryString = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < paramsID.length; i++) {
      var elem = $(paramsID[i]);
      if (elem.val().trim())
        queryString.push((elem.attr('id') || elem.attr('name')) + "=" + escape(elem.val()));
    }
    return queryString.join("&");
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var queryBuilder = new queryStringBuilder(['#dep-filter', '#month-filter', '#user-id', '#desc-id']);
  //Instead of real redirection
  function showQueryString(value) {
    $('#location-search').text(value);
  }
  $('#dep-filter').change(function() {
    showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
  });

  $('#month-filter').change(function() {
    showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
  });

  $('#user-id,#desc-id').change(function() {
    showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
  });
  showQueryString(queryBuilder.getQueryString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <label>Department</label>
    <select id="dep-filter">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Month</label>
    <select id="month-filter">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option selected value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <label>User</label>
    <input id="user-id">
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea id="desc-id"></textarea>
    <div>
      <label>Simulate <b>location</b> query string</label>
      <div id="location-search">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую!

Comment: Попробовал ваш способ,и всеравно у меня фильтры перебивают друг друга

Comment: После перезагрузки queryParams ведь будет храниить последний выбранный селект!

Comment: Здравствуйте. Что вы понимаете под **перезагрузкой?** Если возможно, создайте рабочий [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) с примером.

Comment: Имею в виду что после выбора селекта идет реквест и страница перезагружается.

Comment: Конечно, мы ведь написали соответствующий код для перезагрузки страницы, а именно `location.search= getQueryString();`. Выполнение этого кода производит перезагрузку страницы. Пожалуйста, напишите более развернутый вопрос, чего Вы хотите добиться. Какой конечный результат?

Comment: Сохранение предыдущих фильтров в URL,на данный момент он просто замещают друг друга

Comment: Обновите Ваш вопрос, с примером кода, что вы делаете, что происходит, что хотите, что бы происходило. Очень сложно понимать что хочет человек не видя кода.

Comment: Обновил вопрос,надеюсь доступно пояснил проблему.Код прежний

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста я попробовал ваш код,немного не так работает как должен.Может я чего не правильно сделал?

Comment: Если я правильно понял в вашем скрипте при выборе одного из фильтров строится query string из всех фильтров которые имеются.Я бы хотел чтобы они добавлялись в URL по мере использования.То есть выбрал фильтр dep-id в URL записался ?dep-id=100,далее выбрал второй фильтр он приклеился к URL включая первый фильтр ?dep-id=100&month=2016-03 и так далее,по мере использования фильтров

Comment: @quaresma89 у меня пример в этом ответе (**Выполнить код**) так и работает, как вы описали. А что наблюдаете вы?

Comment: При выборе одного из фильтров query string строится из всех значений фильтров.Цикл пробегает по всем айди фильтров и собирает их значения и строит query string!

Comment: Все спасибо разобрался.Оказывается у меня в фильтре month текущий месяц стоит как selected,поэтому и в url появляется этот параметр!